# Where is my NPC?

Tags: terraria-console

I'm playing the 3ds version of Terraria, and it says Walter wants to move in. However I don't see him anywhere! I have 2 available houses but it won't let me make him live in those spots! please help.

Answer (score 0):

Houses need to meet the NPC's requirements. I honestly think this is where your problem is. NPC's require a hard block to stand on at night, which must be adjacent your house.

Comment: Providing some kind of source to help the OP find the problem, or include the main bullets of house requirements in your post.